# Bluefoot cms for magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, cms, edit

Its a pretty straight forward question, Im looking for a cms page builder as the client requires the ability to edit pages - add widgets and alter the design.

I know bluefoot cms - [link here](https://www.bluefootcms.com) - has been acquired by magento and they will be implementing it into magento 2 - but is there a time scale? Or does no one have any idea on it?

Alternatively does anyone know of any other good cms extensions which might be of use to myself? Bluefoot looks like it will be the best option, but its just not available... as of yet.

Comment: Ideally BluefootCMS will fully integrated into Magento 2.3.
Source:  [link](https://www.williamscommerce.com/blog/popular-bluefoot-cms-page-builder-module-fully-integrated-magento-2-3/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can't wait for this, it'll help with the CMS side of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At Imagine there was a roadmap revealed to state that Bluefoot would be integrated into Magento 2.3 - but in the meantime (& in case that timeline slips) the only way to get it is through an enterprise agreement, v2.1 or greater & by contacting Magento.

> Magento will be providing more details on the integration roadmap in
>   Q1 2017. In the meantime, the current version of Bluefoot CMS (v1.0)
>   will be available exclusively for licensed Magento Enterprise Edition
>   or Enterprise Cloud Edition merchants with Magento version 2.1 and up.
>   Merchants can obtain the extension through their CDM or Account
>   Manager.

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-acquires-technology-behind-bluefoot-cms-page-builder

The 2.3 integrated version will almost certainly require a rewrite of any code that interfaces with Bluefoot.

**UPDATE**

On contacting Magento regarding getting Bluefoot, I got the reply:

> The Bluefoot extension is not available to be integrated at this time.
>   It will become available once it has become integrated into the
>   Magento software in a future version release.

So I guess that Bluefoot is now off the table until 2018.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this and a few demos at MLUK17 thanks for the update though, nice to give other people information on it as well. Here is a link to the roadmap image if anyone is interested:

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DDQHrtjXkAIjzFg.jpg

Comment: @andyjones I guess the question is how long to wait for Magento Commerce - I want to investigate it for implementation now, but is that a waste of time? The implication of locking down new installs is that the rewrite will be comprehensive!

Comment: Well we know that 2.2 will be at GA come September so looks like we will see it come early 2018 late 2017. That is my only thought on it, we did see a demo of it with Ben marks MLUK17 but its only a demo.

Comment: @andyjones I've been in touch with Magento & Bluefoot is no longer available ahead of the integration with Magento

Answer (score 2):

While installing magento 2.3 default package,Bluefoot are not showing in admin panel..Upcoming magento 2.3.1 magento community going to implement bluefoot directly without any integration in enterprise edition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addidtion to [Andy's question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/167570/45764) I'm now wondering if the Bluefoot CMS page builder will be available in the Magento 2.3 open source edition?

I searched for 'bluefoot' in the Magento 2.3 Alpha devdocs and found the the following [page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/modules/bluefoot-cms/iconography.html). But it has a badge that says: '**Magento Commerce Only**'.

Comment: It will be a paid extension for Magento Open Source, however we wont see it for another month or 2 i don't believe.